# Python, histogram from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, histogram

Good time of the day,

I am writting a function in python (I am using Spyder 3.6), which takes as inputs as dataframe and a label of the particular column. The function should return a histogram of that one column.

```
    def plot_dist(daily_returns,asset_name):
        daily_returns[asset_name].plot.hist(bins=20)
        plt.show()
```

The dataframe daily_returns consists of 3 stocks' returns and an index date. 
The function is very simple, but I get the following mistake

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

It is worth mentioning that it works for a simple plot:

```
    def plot_dist(daily_returns,asset_name):
        daily_returns[asset_name].plot()
        plt.show()
```

However, if I run the following function to build a histogram

```
    def plot_dist(daily_returns,asset_name):
        ax = daily_returns.ix[:,[asset_name]]
        ax.plot.hist(bins=20)
        plt.show()
```

it works. I do not like to create an extra dataframe ax and the usage of df.ix[] looks to bulky. I would appreciate if someone could help me to understand why my first function does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show a sample of your data frame?

Comment: Hi @James, thank you for the reply. Unfortunatly, I cannot attach a reduced  file here. But essentialy, this is a typical df with 4 columns and the 5th one (the 1st one at the beginning) reflects the date and does not have a name. Let me please if you still need a dataframe I will try to do smth.